# Возможно ли с помощью Process.Start() развернуть окно уже запущенного процесса?

Tags: c#

```
var xxx = @"c:/prog/xxx.exe"
```

Есть `Process.Start(xxx)`, который запускает процесс.

А можно как нибудь сделать, что бы процесс не запускался, а восстанавливал его?

То есть, перевести процесс из свёрнутого состояния в развёрнутое.

Comment: Это как вообще?

Comment: а как его можно запустить, если он уже запушен? :)

Comment: @Exploding Kitten Извиняюсь, за неправильно поставленный вопрос! Исправил.

Comment: восстановить главное окно приложения? Т.е. перевести из свёрнутого состояния в состояние неразвернутого окна?

Comment: @4per Перевести из свёрнутого состояния в развёрнутое.

Comment: 1. нужно найти процесс по имени запущенного файла

Comment: 2. взять дескриптор главного окна

Comment: 3. отправить главному окну сообщение развернись

Comment: делается не сложно, но не красиво

Comment: @4per 1 2 уже сделаны, а как 3 пункт реализовать, можно кодом?

Comment: [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636721/bring-another-processes-window-to-foreground-when-it-has-showintaskbar-false), меньше минуты гугла :)

Comment: @aepot В гугле искал, но на эту ссылку не натыкался, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void Maximize(Process proc)
{
    WinAPI.ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, WinAPI.Consts.SHOWWINDOW.SW_MAXIMIZE);
}

public void SetFocus(Process proc)
{
    WinAPI.SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
}
```

---

```
/// <summary>
/// Набор WinAPI функций, как есть (Или почти как есть)
/// </summary>
public static class WinAPI
{

    /// <summary>
    ///  Устанавливает состояние показа определяемого окна.
    ///  Если функция завершилась успешно, возвращается значение
    ///  отличное от нуля. Если функция потерпела неудачу,
    ///  возвращаемое значение - ноль.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">Дескриптор окна</param>
    /// <param name="nCmdShow">Определяет, как окно должно быть показано.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///  Если функция завершилась успешно, возвращается значение
    ///  отличное от нуля. Если функция потерпела неудачу,
    ///  возвращаемое значение - ноль.
    ///  </returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    /// <summary>
    ///  Устанавливает состояние показа определяемого окна.
    ///  Если функция завершилась успешно, возвращается значение
    ///  отличное от нуля. Если функция потерпела неудачу,
    ///  возвращаемое значение - ноль.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">Дескриптор окна</param>
    /// <param name="nCmdShow">Определяет, как окно должно быть показано.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///  Если функция завершилась успешно, возвращается значение
    ///  отличное от нуля. Если функция потерпела неудачу,
    ///  возвращаемое значение - ноль.
    ///  </returns>
    public static bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Consts.SHOWWINDOW nCmdShow)
    {
        return ShowWindow(hWnd, (int)nCmdShow);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Установить окно на передний план
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">Handle окна</param>
    /// <returns>Удачность</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);


    /// <summary>
    /// Набор констант
    /// </summary>
    public static class Consts
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Параметры к функции ShowWindow. 
        /// Внимание! Некоторые параметры имеют одинаковое значение
        /// (Почему? За ответом к дяде Биллу)
        /// </summary>
        public enum SHOWWINDOW : uint
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Скрывает окно и активизирует другое окно
            /// </summary>
            SW_HIDE = 0,
            /// <summary>
            /// Активизирует и отображает окно.
            /// Если окно свернуто или развернуто,
            /// Windows восстанавливает его в 
            /// первоначальном размере и позиции. 
            /// Прикладная программа должна установить 
            /// этот флажок при отображении окна впервые
            /// </summary>
            SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1,
            SW_NORMAL = 1,
            /// <summary>
            /// Активизирует окно и отображает его как свернутое окно
            /// </summary>
            SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2,
            /// <summary>
            /// Активизирует окно и отображает его как развернутое окно
            /// </summary>
            SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3,
            /// <summary>
            /// Развертывает определяемое окно
            /// </summary>
            SW_MAXIMIZE = 3,
            /// <summary>
            /// Отображает окно в его самом современном размере и позиции. 
            /// Активное окно остается активным
            /// </summary>
            SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4,
            /// <summary>
            /// Активизирует окно и отображает его текущие размеры и позицию
            /// </summary>
            SW_SHOW = 5,
            /// <summary>
            /// Свертывает определяемое окно и активизирует следующее окно 
            /// верхнего уровня в Z-последовательности
            /// </summary>
            SW_MINIMIZE = 6,
            /// <summary>
            /// Отображает окно как свернутое окно. Активное окно остается активным
            /// </summary>
            SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7,
            /// <summary>
            /// Отображает окно в его текущем состоянии. Активное окно остается активным
            /// </summary>
            SW_SHOWNA = 8,
            /// <summary>
            /// Активизирует и отображает окно. 
            /// Если окно свернуто или развернуто, 
            /// Windows восстанавливает в его первоначальных 
            /// размерах и позиции. Прикладная программа должна 
            /// установить этот флажок при восстановлении свернутого окна
            /// </summary>
            SW_RESTORE = 9,
            /// <summary>
            /// Устанавливает состояние показа, основанное на флажке SW_
            /// , определенном в структуре STARTUPINFO, 
            /// переданной в функцию CreateProcess программой, 
            /// которая запустила прикладную программу
            /// </summary>
            SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10,
            /// <summary>
            /// Windows 2000/XP: Свертывает окно, даже если поток,
            /// который владеет окном, зависает. Этот флажок должен 
            /// быть использоваться только при свертывании окон 
            /// другого потока
            /// </summary>
            SW_FORCEMINIMIZE = 11,
            SW_MAX = 11,
        }
    }
}
```